# To display year in sorted order through array of structures

Tags: c

My question is to make a structure containing three members i.e. day , month and year and we have to supply year of joining of 10 employees through keyboard. The year supplied should be displayed back to the user in increasing order of the year ?

So i have used array of structures and then supplied the values using scanf() function and later i have make use of bubble sort to sort the year supplied . But it seems that i am having problem in scanf() . I am facing run-time error in my code . What's the mistake in my code . Please Help.

Below is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int *, int *);
int main()
{
int i, j;

typedef struct date
{
    char day : 5;

    char month : 4;

    int year : 12;

}D;

D arr[10];

printf("Enter year of joining of 10 employees\n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    scanf_s("%d", arr[i].year);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i].year > arr[j].year)
            swap(arr[i].year, arr[j].year);

    }

}

printf("Value of employees joining year in sorted order is : \n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d", arr[i].year);

return 0;

}

void swap(int *x, int *y)
 {
  int temp;

  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;

  }
```

Comment: Try `scanf_s("%d", arr[i]->year)`

Comment: scanf() needs a pointer, so write &arr[i].year. PS: Don't use scanf_s() and 'friends'.

Answer (score 0):

The two main problems are using bitfields, and not passing pointers to functions.

There is litle point using bitfields here: the size of the struct is 8 whether  they are bitfields or simple integer types.

But where an actual problem arises, is that in `scanf_s` and `swap` you are supposed to pass a *pointer* to the bitfields, and the compiler (MSVC) does not like that.

So remove the bitfield specs and add an address-of operator to the calls.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct date
{
    char day;                                      // remove bitfield spcs
    char month;
    int year;
} D;

void swap(int *, int *);

int main(void)
    {
    int i, j;
    D arr[10];

    printf("Enter year of joining of 10 employees\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i].year);               // add the & operator

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i].year > arr[j].year)
                swap(&arr[i].year, &arr[j].year);  // add & operators
        }
    }

    printf("Value of employees joining year in sorted order is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i].year);
    return 0;
}

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

But I would say this is still deficient. Why swap just the year? I suggest you should be swapping the day and month too: the whole `struct`.